# FSTab, manage 2 boot partitions 'priority'?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

My FSTab `/etc/fstab`allows 2 boots partitions, one on the machine HDD (where there are `swap`and FS `/`), another on a USB pendrive.

I duplicated the `boot` line in `/etc/fstab` and changed the UUID and format:

```
UUID=</boot partition on HDD> /boot ext2 defaults 0 2
UUID=</boot partition on USB> /boot vfat defaults 0 2
```

Can I tell FSTAb to **"priorize"** USB ? How ?

Thanks a lot (*I promise I googled, but maybe with not-right words...*)

**EDIT** What am I aiming ? This process: if USB is plugged then *use USB /boot*, else: *use HDD boot*.

Why am I aiming that ? Because my USB pendrive contains a LUKS-keyfile registered in `/etc/crypttab`. Maybe I dont even need to boot *from* USB, but I need to *only* **mount** it ; anyway `crypt` has to get my key.

It's a *fallback* plan: no USB ? give the LUKS text passphrase input. USB ? get the keyfile from USB mounted drive.

Comment: You are trying to do something wrong. Why do you want to mount two partitions to the same directory, especially to /boot?

Comment: You'd better explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Pilot6 I dont want, actually, do that exactly. I want to use USB /boot. But if USB is not plugged, I want to use HDD /boot.

Comment: Why do you want it to be mounted to /boot? You can mount it somewhere else with `nofail` parameter.

Comment: Originally, I wanted to disable /boot if the USB is not plugged. But finally I prefer the *fallback* process. Thank you @Pilot6 , I'm going to get the `nofail`stuff. You should post an answer, rather than comment, ? BR

Comment: I converted to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to setup automounting options in fstab to mount two partitions to the same mount point.

You can mount your pen drive somewhere else with `nofail` parameter.

You will not get error messages if pen drive is not plugged.

Comment: Thank you. If I want my pendrive : stores the keyfile (added to `/etc/crypttab`) and allows to auto enter my linux session (avoiding to have to manually enter the passphrase), shouldnt I boot on the pendrive ? and comment the usual /boot in `etc/fstab` ?

Comment: I am not an expert in encryption, but I think you do not have to boot from the pendrive. You can mount it somewhere and setup the path in /etc/crypttab to it.

Comment: I did. For now, no success. I'm still proposed the text-input for passphrase.

Comment: I suggest asking another question that makes it clear that you want to have a key on your pen drive.